# document.querySelector() return null with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to get a textarea in python with selenium. When i go to the browser, i open the console and i send this :

```
document.querySelector('[id^="h-captcha-response-"]')
```

I get my textarea, it's perfect.

> textarea id="h-captcha-response-0l5458ke7qc" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;">

And when i do this command in python with selenium and i want to fill the .innerHTML like :

```
driver.execute_script(f'''                                                                                                                                                             
document.querySelector('[id^="h-captcha-response-"]').innerHTML = "{code}"                                                                                                             
''')
```

It's say :

> selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Why do I get this error ? On my browser's console I can select the textarea without any problem so why my textarea is null now ?

Thank you for your answer

Joss

Comment: Could you post the websites url for us to test with?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Ok It works i didn't know but the webdriver has to switch tab to find new elements, and this text areas is in a new tab, so my execute_script was executed in the wrong tab. Thanks bro